# Setting content control title

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I am having an issue with setting a Content Control value using VBS. Here is what I am doing:

```
Sub saveToWord
    Set docObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    docObj.visible =true
    docObj.Documents.open "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.docx"
    docObj.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Title").Item(1).Range.Text = "Test title"
End Sub
```

It works perfectly in VBA,but it doesn't work for VBScript. There is an error:

`Object doesn't support this property or method: 'docObj.SelectContentControlsByTitle'`

Are there any alternatives to achieve this? I had a look into [ContentControls Object Docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/contentcontrols-object-word), but couldn't find any suitable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you assign the Word.Application to the variable docObject. SelectContentControlsByTitle is a member of the DOCUMENT, not the Application object. You need something more like

```
 Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 wdApp.Visible = true
 Set docObject = Documents.Open(fileName)
 'Etc.
```

Comment: Have done the following: `Set docObject = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.docx")` and then `docObject.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Title").Item(1).Range.Text = "Test title"`. But, nothing is changed somehow. There is no any error, but no changes.

Comment: Well, this has solved the original question, yes? The error message is gone. So now you have a new question, which you should post as new so the code can be clearly formatted and the discussion won't get so complex. However, two tests come to mind: 1) Do a .Count on the SelectContentControlsByTitle, to see if it returns 1; 2) Write some text to the content control in the Word UI and see if you can read the text.